# Rhel 7.6 having python 2.7.5 default will it support pexpect 4.6.0 and argparse?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, rhel7

Does RHEL 7.6 supports pexpect version 4.6.0 it has default python version 2.7.5?  What is the latest version of pexpect which is supported on RHEL 7.6 having python 2.7.5.

Also what version of argparse is supported with python 2.7.5

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: In case the packages you intend to use aren't supported by the native Python version, you could use virtual environment ( https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/ ) to setup the desired version of Python.

Comment: Thanks for the response .. I have not tried but wanted to know if there is someplace I can check which lists the supported python version for those packages(pexpect and argparse along with python version . Link  for pexpect but i didnt find anything related to supported python version